# Chrome's right-click window is changed?

Tags: google-chrome

[The Right click Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG3uL.png)

Why is the Chrome Right Click Window so small is there any way to revert it please?
i do not know how it became like this

Comment: (Preface: I don’t use Chrome.) Looks pretty normal to me, it’s more or less the same as Windows menus generally are. How do you expect to be different? Larger fonts? Larger padding/margins?

Comment: It had more Padding Before also a little bit of a margin in the left but now that is all cut out and it look... weird

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i do not know how it became like this

Google released a new version of Chrome with some changes to its UI. Your Chrome installation automatically updated itself to the new version and you're now seeing the changes.

It seems they broke the old design while in the process of implementing the new one. Visiting `chrome://flags` and enabling "Chrome Refresh 2023" will enable the new design, which mostly returns the menu appearance to normal.

Comment: It shows the new design that looks like windows 11 but ya i guess they broke the old one

Comment: Everytime I try to click 'Inspect' in the menu it updates the menu to another layout and I click 'view page source' instead..incredibly annoying, thakns for this fix